# Is it faster to check if a subtring exists before removing it?

Tags: python, replace

Is a faster to check if a subtring (in my case a whitespace) exists in a string before removing it, or to use `relace()` globally, as a matter of speaking;

Use case:

```
a = ['452 04','45204','455 04','88804']
for i,e in enumerate(a):
    if re.search(r"\s", e):
       a[i] = e.replace(' ','')
```

Any other suggestions are welcome, too.

Comment: I did not. I thought someone might be able to answer out of experience?

Comment: my experience is 1) the simple program is the better program 2) if you want to *know* if your program would be faster under different conditions the only way is to time your specific code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import re

def with_re_search():
    a = ['452 04','45204','455 04','88804']
    for i,e in enumerate(a):
        if re.search(r"\s", e):
            a[i] = e.replace(' ','')

def with_in():
    a = ['452 04','45204','455 04','88804']
    for i,e in enumerate(a):
        if ' ' in e:
            a[i] = e.replace(' ','')

def without_search():
    a = ['452 04','45204','455 04','88804']
    for i,e in enumerate(a):
        a[i] = e.replace(' ','')

def with_translate():
    a = ['452 04','45204','455 04','88804']
    for i, e in enumerate(a):
        a[i] = e.translate(None,'')

from timeit import timeit as t
n = 1000000
t('f()', setup='from __main__ import with_re_search as f', number=n) # 5.37417006493
t('f()', setup='from __main__ import with_in as f',        number=n) # 1.04646992683
t('f()', setup='from __main__ import without_search as f', number=n) # 1.2475438118
t('f()', setup='from __main__ import with_translate as f', number=n) # 1.56214690208
```

Using `re.search` was absolutely slower than other options.

This was done in CPython 2.7.3, Ubuntu Linux 12.10 64bit.

**UPDATE**: In CPython 3.3.0 (the same machine).

```
t('f()', setup='from __main__ import with_re_search as f', number=n) # 24.345079875027295
t('f()', setup='from __main__ import with_in as f',        number=n) # 1.1399168980424292
t('f()', setup='from __main__ import without_search as f', number=n) # 1.3967725560069084
```

*NOTE* couldn't time `str.translate`, because [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) in Python 3 does not accept `deletechars` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about removing only the spaces, you can use `translate`.

```
a = ['452 04','45204','455 04','88804']
a = [item.translate(None, " ") for item in a]
print a
```

Comment: @falsetru Sorry. Fixed that.